# CSS issue with multiple footers and fluid grid in mobile view

Tags: html, css, grid, footer, fluid

I have 3 footer areas in a fluid grid website I'm designing.  There is a top copyright footer above the two left and right floated footers (I'm calling them widgets even though they aren't). The layout looks fine in desktop, but I'd like the widget footers to both align left and stack as blocks below each other in mobile view.  They *almost* do it - but the footer that I have floated right won't align left in mobile.

I've inserted the css as an inline style into the html code below:

```
<style>
.fluid {
    clear: both;
    margin-left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
    display: block;
}

.fluidList {
    list-style:none;
    list-style-image:none;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;        
}
#page {
    margin: 40px auto;
    padding: 0 1em;
    max-width: 61.75em;     /* 988px / 16px = 61.75em */

}
h1 {
    font-family: 'EB Garamond', serif;
    font-size: 1.55em;
    letter-spacing: .18em;
    font-style:normal;
    text-transform:uppercase;

}
h2 {
    font-family: 'EB Garamond', serif;
    font-size: 1.55em;
    letter-spacing: .11em;
    font-style:normal;
    text-transform:capitalize;

}
h4 {
    font-family: 'EB Garamond', serif;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    letter-spacing: .08em;
    font-style: normal;
    color: #73624d;
    margin-top: -5px;
    }

#mainNav {  
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 40px auto; 
    background-color: #fff; 
    font-family:"Century Gothic", "HelveticaNeueLT Pro 45 Lt", sans-serif; 
    font-size:16px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    float:right;
    z-index: 1000;

}
#mainNav ul {
    text-align:center;
    }
#mainNav li { 
    list-style: none; 
    float: left; 
    width: 140px;  
    height: 30px; 
    line-height: 30px; 
    text-align: left;
}
#mainNav li a { 
    color: #73624d; 
    text-decoration: none; 
    display: block; 
}
#mainNav li a:hover {
    background-color: #d9e2e7;
    text-align: left;
}
#mainNav li ul { 
    position: absolute;  
    display: none; 
} 
#mainNav li:hover ul { 
    display: block; 
}
#mainNav li ul li { 
    float: none; 
    display: inline; 
}
#mainNav li ul li a { 
    width: 190px; 
    position: relative; 
    padding: 0 0 0 4px;
    border-left: 1px solid #2c2216; 
    border-right: 1px solid #2c2216; 
    border-bottom: 1px solid #2c2216; 
    background: #73624d; 
    color: #fff; 
}
#mainNav li ul li a:hover { 
    background: #d9e2e7; 
    color: #000; 
}
/* Mobile Layout: 480px and below. */

.gridContainer {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 96.6666%;
    padding-left: 1.6666%;
    padding-right: 1.6666%;
    clear: none;
    float: none;
}
#div1 {
}
.logo {
    text-align: center;
}

#mainContent {
}
#slider {
}

#footerCopy {
    text-align:center;
    font-family: 'EB Garamond', serif;
    font-size: 15px;
    letter-spacing: .04em;
    margin: 10px auto;
    }
#widget {
    text-align: center;
    }
#widget p{
    font-size: 13px;
    }
#footer1 {
    margin: 5px 25px;
    display:block;
    float:left; 
    }
#footer2 {
    margin: 5px 25px;
    display: block;
    float: right;
    }
.zeroMargin_mobile {
margin-left: 0;
}
.hide_mobile {
display: none;
}

/* Tablet Layout: 481px to 768px. Inherits styles from: Mobile Layout. */

@media only screen and (min-width: 481px) {

.gridContainer {
    width: 98.6111%;
    padding-left: 0.6944%;
    padding-right: 0.6944%;
    clear: none;
    float: none;
    margin-left: auto;
}

#div1 {
}
.logo {
}
#mainContent {
}
.dmxNivoSlider {
    clear:both;
    }
#widget {
    text-align: left;
    }
#footer1 {
    margin: 5px 25px;
    display:block;
    float:left; 
    }
#footer2 {
    margin: 5px 25px;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    }
.hide_tablet {
display: none;
}
.zeroMargin_tablet {
margin-left: 0;
}

</style>
<div class="gridContainer clearfix">
  <div id="div1" class="fluid">
        <header class="fluid logo"><img src="_images/CGDA_Logo.png" alt="Collins Group Design Logo"/></header>
  </div>
     <div id="page">
 <nav class="mainNav" id="mainNav">
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">About</a>
              <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Our Approach</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Our Team</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Accolades</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Awards | Publications</a></li>
               </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Design </a>
              <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Process</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Value | Expectations</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">FAQ</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Fee Structure</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
             <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a>
              <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Kitchen | Bath</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Living | Dining</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Bedrooms | Hobby Rooms</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Entry | Halls</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Bespoke Furniture</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Bespoke</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
          </ul>
        </nav>

   <article id="mainContent" class="fluid">

     <div id="slider1" class="dmxNivoSlider slider-wrapper theme-basic" style="">
        <div class="nivoSlider"><img id="img_UC_Slide2" src="_images/UC-Slide2.jpg" alt="" data-thumb="_images/thumbs/UC-Slide2.jpg" />
        <img id="img_UC_Slide3" src="_images/UC-Slide3.jpg" alt="" data-thumb="_images/thumbs/UC-Slide3.jpg" />
        <img id="img_UC_Slide4" src="_images/UC-Slide4.jpg" alt="" data-thumb="_images/thumbs/UC-Slide4.jpg" />
        <img id="img_UC_Slide5" src="_images/UC-Slide5.jpg" alt="" data-thumb="_images/thumbs/UC-Slide5.jpg" />
        </div>
      </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      // <![CDATA[
    jQuery(document).ready(
     function()
     {
       jQuery("#slider1").dmxNivoSlider(
         {"pauseTime": 4000, "dataSource": ""}
       );
     }
     );
         // ]]>
    </script>

</article>
<footer class="fluid">
    <div id="footerCopy">
        &copy; 2014 Collins Group Design, Inc. All rights reserved.
    </div>
    <hr>
    <div id="widget">
        <div id="footer1">
            <h4> Contact Us:</h4>
            <p>&#9742; &nbsp;<a href="tel:206-919-5474">206.919.5474</a></p>
            <p>&#9993; &nbsp;<a href="mailto:info@collinsgroupdesign.com?Subject=Website%20Inquiry" target="_top">Collins Group Design</a></p>
            </div>
        <div id="footer2">
            <h4>Stay In Touch:</h4>
            <img src="_images/icons/Facebook.png" alt="Visit Collins Group Design on Facebook"/> 
            <img src="_images/icons/LinkedIn.png" alt="Visit Collins Group Design on LinkedIn"/> 
            <img src="_images/icons/Pinterest.png" alt="Visit Collins Group Design on Pinterest"/> 
            <img src="_images/icons/Twitter.png" alt="Visit Collins Group Design on Twitter"/>
         </div>
       </div>
  </footer>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set `#footer1` and `#footer2` as `float: none` for mobiles. Only float them for the wider views.

```
#footer1, #footer2 {
    margin: 5px 25px;
    display: block;
    float: none; /* <- or don't even declare this as it's float none by default */
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 481px) {
    #footer1, #footer2 {
       float:left;
    }
    /* ...etc... */
}
```

```css
.fluid {
    clear: both;
    margin-left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
    display: block;
}
h4 {
    font-family:'EB Garamond', serif;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    letter-spacing: .08em;
    font-style: normal;
    color: #73624d;
    margin-top: -5px;
}
/* Mobile Layout: 480px and below. */
 .gridContainer {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 96.6666%;
    padding-left: 1.6666%;
    padding-right: 1.6666%;
    clear: none;
    float: none;
}
#div1 {
}
.logo {
    text-align: center;
}
#mainContent {
}
#slider {
}
#footerCopy {
    text-align:center;
    font-family:'EB Garamond', serif;
    font-size: 15px;
    letter-spacing: .04em;
    margin: 10px auto;
}
#widget {
    text-align: center;
}
#widget p {
    font-size: 13px;
}
#footer1 {
    margin: 5px 25px;
    display:block;
    float:none;
}
#footer2 {
    margin: 5px 25px;
    display: block;
    float: none;
}
.zeroMargin_mobile {
    margin-left: 0;
}
.hide_mobile {
    display: none;
}
/* Tablet Layout: 481px to 768px. Inherits styles from: Mobile Layout. */
 @media only screen and (min-width: 481px) {
    .gridContainer {
        width: 98.6111%;
        padding-left: 0.6944%;
        padding-right: 0.6944%;
        clear: none;
        float: none;
        margin-left: auto;
    }
    #div1 {
    }
    .logo {
    }
    #mainContent {
    }
    .dmxNivoSlider {
        clear:both;
    }
    #widget {
        text-align: left;
    }
    #footer1 {
        margin: 5px 25px;
        display:block;
        float:left;
    }
    #footer2 {
        margin: 5px 25px;
        display: block;
        float: left;
    }
    .hide_tablet {
        display: none;
    }
    .zeroMargin_tablet {
        margin-left: 0;
    }
}
```

```html
<footer class="fluid">
    <div id="footerCopy">&copy; 2014 Collins Group Design, Inc. All rights reserved.</div>
    <hr>
    <div id="widget">
        <div id="footer1">
             <h4> Contact Us:</h4>

            <p>&#9742; &nbsp;<a href="tel:206-919-5474">206.919.5474</a>

            </p>
            <p>&#9993; &nbsp;<a href="mailto:info@collinsgroupdesign.com?Subject=Website%20Inquiry" target="_top">Collins Group Design</a>

            </p>
        </div>
        <div id="footer2">
             <h4>Stay In Touch:</h4>

            <img src="_images/icons/Facebook.png" alt="Visit Collins Group Design on Facebook" />
            <img src="_images/icons/LinkedIn.png" alt="Visit Collins Group Design on LinkedIn" />
            <img src="_images/icons/Pinterest.png" alt="Visit Collins Group Design on Pinterest" />
            <img src="_images/icons/Twitter.png" alt="Visit Collins Group Design on Twitter" />
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you should float both footers left on mobile using your media queries

**Update**

To make them stack below each other also add `display: block` to them on mobile

Comment: alan, if you scroll down to my @media query for mobile, isn't that what I did? Did I do it wrong?

Comment: hmm your media query looks fine, when you inspect the footers with your browser screen at mobile width can you see that the css is being applied?

Comment: No, not at mobile view.  Here's a link to a [screenshot](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/4189611/Screen%20Shot%202014-10-29%20at%2010.32.11%20AM.png) of what I get

Comment: right so you want the 'stay in touch' and social icons aligned left? set their position: relative and left: 0